# Finding IDs that have been consistently failing to meet target

Tags: python, pandas

It's my first time here on stack exchange.
I have table with data columns including ID, Domain, Target and Dates (The table seen below). I am currently performing analysis on it and having trouble in finding which IDs have been failing consistently to meet the target.

Code

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# Create sample dataframe
 raw_data = {'ID': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'], 
'Domain': ['Finance', 'IT', 'IT', 'Finance'], 
'Target': [1, 2, 3, >1], 
"1/01":[0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1],
"1/02":[0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9], 
"1/03":[1, 1, 0.5, 1.1], 
"1/04":[0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 1],
"1/05":[0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 1], 
"1/06":[0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1]}


 df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID', 'Domain', 'Target', '1/01', 
'1/02','1/03', '1/04','1/05', '1/06'])
```

The main question that i must answer is

1. Which ID has been failing consistently, How many times?
2. Which ID have been meet consistently, beating the target very comfortably?

Can someone please help me ? I'm really new to this pandas and data analysis

Comment: You have to specify what do you mean by beating the target (beating one target for a given period ? or all of them ?), what do you mean by consistently (proportions of months failing over total month ? lenght of the fail strike ?), what do you mean by confortably ? (0.1 ahead of the target ? 0.2 ? we can't define that for you as we don't know what it would represent).